# SFTP File Download in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-integration-sftp

I created one spring boot app. I need to upload any file(doc,pdf,mp3 etc..) on sftp server. when user upload file my spring app can able to create url and save file details(on which server file is located, download url of file, who is the own of that file etc..) to h2 database.
and when user ask for file.. spring boot can able to fetch file details form database.. and display that file on browser. and user can also able to download that file. can any one help..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNu4x.jpg)

> Java Configuration

```
import com.example.springintegrationhttp.FilePrinter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.expression.common.LiteralExpression;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileNameGenerator;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.outbound.SftpMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.File;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@Component
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory(){
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setHost("0.0.0.0");
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPort(22);
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setUser("abhishek");
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPassword("12345");
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        System.out.println("Value in SftpSession: " + defaultSftpSessionFactory);
        return defaultSftpSessionFactory;
    }
        @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tosftpChannel")
        public MessageHandler handler(){
            SftpMessageHandler messageHandler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
            messageHandler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("upload"));
            messageHandler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {
                @Override
                public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
                    System.out.println(message.getHeaders().get("fileName"));
                    System.out.println(message.getPayload());
                    return message.getHeaders().get("fileName").toString();
                }
            });
            return messageHandler;
        }

    @Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer(){
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("upload");
        System.out.println("M a gaya");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }
    @Bean
    //@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))//,autoStartup = "false")
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel")//,autoStartup = "false")
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource(){
        System.out.println("Into sftpMessageSource()");
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("target/foo"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        System.out.println("Flow");
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        source.setMaxFetchSize(1);
        //sftpInboundFileSynchronizer();
        return source;
    }

    /*OutBoundGateway*/
      /*  @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel",)
        public MessageHandler handler(){
            SftpOutboundGateway outboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(),
                    "get","payload");
            outboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("target/gatewayhand"));
            outboundGateway.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
            return outboundGateway;
        }*/
    /*OutBoundGateway*/


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler DownloadHandler(){
        //return new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(),"ls");
       return message -> {
           System.out.println("In Service Activator: " + message.getPayload());

           File f = (File) message.getPayload();
           FilePrinter f2 = new FilePrinter();
           f2.print(f);
           System.out.println(f.getName());
           //sftpMessageSource();
           //p.print(File file);

       };
    }
}
```

> Gateway

```
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Component
@MessagingGateway
public interface UplaodGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "tosftpChannel")
    public void sendToSftp(@Header("fileName") String fileName, InputStream file);
   /* @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpChannel")
    public void read(String fileName);*/
}
```

> Controller

```
import com.example.springintegrationhttp.service.UploadService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
//@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class uplaodController {

    @Autowired
    UploadService uploadService;

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> upladFile(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        return uploadService.uplaodToServer(file);
    }
    @GetMapping("/read")
    public String readf(@PathParam("fileName")String fileName){
      uploadService.readFileFromServer(fileName);
        return "I want to fetch that file which user want";
    }
}

//}
```

Thank You

Comment: What is the (specific) problem you are facing? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes I .. i tried.. i can uplaod file on sftp server but i m not able to generate url and download file form sftp server to local machine

Comment: share some code part where you are facing this issue

Comment: I have added code.